# Xamarin Forms - font size on a XAML Label wont seem to change when set

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.forms

In a cross-platform Xamarin Forms app I have a XAML page where I set the style of a label.
No matter whether I set it using static resource styling or within XAML it's self, the font size never changes.

XAML only:

```
<Label 
                            x:Name="DescriptionLabel" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="End"
                            Opacity="0.7" 
                            FontSize="Large"
                            FontFamily="Helvetica Neue"
                            TextColor="#E9F2F8"/>
```

XAML and Style:

```
<Label
                            x:Name="HeaderLabel" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" 
                            HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="End"
                           Opacity="0.7" 
                            Style="{ StaticResource HeaderStyle }"/>

<Style x:Key="HeaderStyle" TargetType="Label" >
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#eb84b5" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24.0">
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

I've tried using both doubles and string for the size (ie  "12.0" or "Medium" etc) but no matter what I try I can never get the font size to change, it always appears small.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: Your XAML looks fine. Have you tried removing other properties in your label which could have been interfering with your font size? Perhaps "HorizontalTextAlignment"?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, could you try placing the label in an empty `Gird` or `StackLayout`? It would also be very helpful, if you can provide a basic demo that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks guys, will have a go at these and update with the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have worked this out by now, but for the others looking for an answer, it seems that having both Font and FontSize or FontFamily attributes set, might be conflicting each other. I think Font overwrites the other. Font supports multiple arguments and you can pass each one inside of it.

(I am no expert, just had the same issue and this fixed it for me)

> To specify multiple Font settings, combine the required settings into a single Font attribute string. The font attribute string should be formatted as "[font-face],[attributes],[size]". The order of the parameters is important, all parameters are optional, and multiple attributes can be specified, for example:"

```
<Label Text="Medium custom font" Font="MarkerFelt-Thin, 42" />
<Label Text="Really big bold and italic text" Font="Bold, Italic, 72"  />
```

[From the official documentation of Xamarin.Forms site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts)